# CSS Place Text inside Grid Tiles

Tags: html, css

I made a basic CSS Grid, and now I want to place the text inside the tiles on a certain Position but I have no clue how to do it. This picture should show what I mean:

[image]

The Blue box is where I want the Text to be.

```css
.tiles {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 2fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  height: 1150px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box1 {
  background: #3030c9;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="tiles">
  <div class="box box1">
    <h1 id="text">Test</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="box box2">Test</div>
  <div class="box box3">Test</div>
  <div class="box box4">Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean  with certain Position? Like centered in box ?

Comment: On the screenshot you see a Blue box(in the first tile) this is where i want it to be

Comment: I can't see screenshot. It's not opened for me. Can you give me a link ?

Comment: grid-area for a child when  you have no grid-template-area set in the parent , how do you expect it to match any cells ? grid-row:span:2 would work better i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the `box1` class a flex column that centers vertically, then just add some margin to the left of the header.

```css
.tiles {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 2fr);
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  height: 1150px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box2 {
  background: #7d30c9;
}
.box3 {
  background: #c93030;
}
.box4 {
  background: #30c9c9;
}

.box1 {
  background: #3030c9;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box1 h1 {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="tiles">
  <div class="box box1">
    <h1 id="text">Test</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="box box2">Test</div>
  <div class="box box3">Test</div>
  <div class="box box4">Test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. Your screen shot couldn't be opened for me. Anyway if you want to replace text a specific position in box first way selecting text with id.

```
#text{
  margin-left:40%;
  margin-top:20%; // You can give px or rem 
}
```

If you want to text align you can add it into box class. This aligns your text according to the box

```
.box1 {
  background: #3030c9;
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
  text-align :center // or left ,right

}
```

Answer (score -1):

add position:relative to .box1 and position:absolute to your h1 tag and also set left and top values to your h1 as desired